# Should I grout the walls or floor first?

Tags: tile, grout, tiling

I have finished tiling my shower and am ready to grout. The walls are LFT 6x24 tiles and the floor is natural stone pebbles. The grout color for the wall tiles is slightly darker than the grout color for the floor. Do I grout the walls or the floor first?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can not think of a reason that it matters.

I would do the walls first, i would protect the floor with some heavy duty plastic sheeting taped down at the edges.

Wait a day and Then do the floor, use painter tape around the base of the walls.

After the grout has cure for a day then you can pull the tape off the walls and caulk the joint where the floor meets the walls with 100% silicone, mold and mildew resistant caulk.

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't matter. Just cover the floor with a towel or plastic to keep it clean when you grout the wall.